# append div with another div content using xpath

Tags: xpath, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I want to append div using xpath inheriting a parent template.

for ex.
this is parent template

```
<template id="parent_id">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <h1> HEADER </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="product">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- THERE IS SOME CONTENT -->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

i want to change like this,

```
<template id="parent_id">
    <div id="product">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- THERE IS SOME CONTENT -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

i try this,

```
<template id="product_custom" inherit_id="parent_id">
    <xpath expr="//div[@id='product']" position="after">
        <div class="inner">
    </xpath>
</template>
```

while replace all content is easy or copy all content to custom template, but it not proper way. i want to wrap a div on content.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do that, because you are going either to override the content or to place your `<div/>` before, after on inside the selected element.

A simple solution will be to give the `id="product"` div the class `inner` by using `position="attributes"`. Or if you really need this, a possible solution is:

1. replace `id="product"` with `class="inner"` with one override using `attributes` position
2. define your own template in a second override and call the original one inside it

You will end up with something like this:

```
  <template id="my_parent" inherit_id="foo.parent_id">
    <div id="product">
      <t t-call="foo.parent_id" />
    </div>
  </template>
```

plus the override of the attributes. Never done something like this and the code above is not tested but it could work ;)

Comment: Thanks, i also try `position="attributes"` it work but not actually i want. and your another solution is great it solve problem but in my case it not work.

Comment: can you provide more info about this? w/out example I cannot help.

Comment: i update my question, in parent template there is possible more content. but i want wrap specific content so i think `t-call` not work.

Comment: Then I think you cannot do that :)
So, I think you 2 options: 1. rewrite it  2. use JS to wrap the element on the fly